# ASAN heap use after free

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, free, address-sanitizer

I am running ASAN for finding memory leaks in a very big project. I have found out the cause, but do not know how to resolve it. I have made a sample program to make the problem understandable.
In the below program I can only work-around on specified code. For rest of the code it is not possible to do work around.
So please suggest what work around I may have to resolve below ASAN error.
(How to make pointer two as NULL using t1?)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct l
{
    int a, b;
}pack;

void delete_me(pack *ap)
{
    free(ap);
}

int main(void)
{
    pack **d_ptr = (pack **)malloc(3 * sizeof(pack *));
    pack *one, *two, *three;
    one = (pack *)malloc(sizeof(pack));
    one->a = 1, one->b = 2;
    two = (pack *)malloc(sizeof(pack));
    two->a = 3, two->b = 4;
    three = (pack *)malloc(sizeof(pack));
    three->a = 5, three->b = 6;
    d_ptr[0] = one;
    d_ptr[1] = two;
    d_ptr[2] = three;

    // I can Only work-around below code (4 lines)
    pack *t1 = d_ptr[1]; // For which index t1 would be assigned, is not known before hand
    t1->a = 1; t1->b = 2;
    printf("a: %d, b: %d\n", two->a, two->b);
    delete_me(t1); // How to delete t1 so that corresponding pointer also becomes NULL?
    // Work around only till here was possible.

    // Below this, No workaround possible.
    if (two && (two->a == one->a)) // ASAN ERROR
            printf("ERROR\n");
    else
            printf("It works!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

ASAN Error:
ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free

Comment: `two` == `t1`. You can't use one if you delete the other.

Comment: For that only I am first checking whether two is NULL. But it seems deleting t1 does not make two as NULL.

Comment: This is C, not C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately your problem isn't really solvable.

When you have multiple copies of the same pointer, e.g.

```
int *p1 = malloc(sizeof (int));
int *p2 = p1;
int *p3 = p2;
```

then freeing any of them invalidates all of them:

```
free(p2);
// Now p1, p2, p3 have invalid values.
// The C standard calls these "indeterminate values"; accessing them has undefined behavior
```

You can manually set `p2` to `NULL` after freeing, but that still leaves `p1` and `p3` dangling. You cannot automatically find all copies of a pointer value that may exist anywhere in your program's memory.

You need to restructure the logic of your program. There is no quick and easy fix.